# Parse nested custom yaml tags

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have some yaml with application-specific tags (from an AWS Cloud Formation template, to be exact) that looks like this:

```
example_yaml = "Name: !Join [' ', ['EMR', !Ref 'Environment', !Ref 'Purpose']]"
```

I want to parse it so that I can do this:

```
>>> print(result)
>>> {'Name': 'EMR {Environment} {Purpose}'}

>>> name = result['name'].format(
...    Environment='Development',
...    Purpose='ETL'
... )
>>> print(name)
>>> EMR Development ETL
```

Currently my code looks like this:

```
import yaml
from pprint import pprint


def aws_join(loader, node):
    join_args = loader.construct_yaml_seq(node)
    delimiter = list(join_args)[0]
    joinables = list(join_args)[1]
    join_result = delimiter.join(joinables)
    return join_result

def aws_ref(loader, node):
    value = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    placeholder = '{'+value+'}'
    return placeholder

yaml.add_constructor('!Join', aws_join)
yaml.add_constructor('!Ref', aws_ref)

example_yaml = "Name: !Join [' ', ['EMR', !Ref 'Environment', !Ref 'Purpose']]"

pprint(yaml.load(example_yaml))
```

Unfortunately this results in an error.

```
...
   joinables = list(join_args)[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Adding `print('What I am: '+str(join_args))` to `aws_join` shows that I'm getting a generator:

```
What I am: <generator object SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_seq at 0x1082ece08>
```

That's why I tried to cast the generator as a list. The generator eventually populates correctly though, just not in time for me to use it. If I change my `aws_join` function to like this:

```
def aws_join(loader, node):
    join_args = loader.construct_yaml_seq(node)
    return join_args
```

Then the final result looks like this:

```
{'Name': [' ', ['EMR', '{Environment}', '{Purpose}']]}
```

So the required pieces to my function are there, just not when I need them in my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but the problem is that you are using the method
`construct_yaml_seq()`.  That method is actually a registered
constructor for the normal YAML sequence (the one that eventually makes
a Python list) and it calls the `construct_sequence()` method to handle the
node that gets passed in, and that is what you should do as well.

As you are returning a string, which cannot deal with recursive data
structures, you don't need to use the two step creation process (first
`yield`-ing, then filling out) which the `construct_yaml_seq()` method
follows. But this two step creation process is *why you encountered a
generator*.

`construct_sequence` returns a simple list, but as you want the nodes
underneath the `!Join` available when you start processing, make sure
to specify the `deep=True` parameter, otherwise the second list
element will be an empty list. And because `construct_yaml_seq()`,
doesn't specify `deep=True`, you did not get the pieces in time in
your function (otherwise you could have actually used that method).

```
import yaml
from pprint import pprint


def aws_join(loader, node):
    join_args = loader.construct_sequence(node, deep=True)
    # you can comment out next line
    assert join_args == [' ', ['EMR', '{Environment}', '{Purpose}']] 
    delimiter = join_args[0]
    joinables = join_args[1]
    return delimiter.join(joinables)

def aws_ref(loader, node):
    value = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    placeholder = '{'+value+'}'
    return placeholder

yaml.add_constructor('!Join', aws_join, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
yaml.add_constructor('!Ref', aws_ref, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

example_yaml = "Name: !Join [' ', ['EMR', !Ref 'Environment', !Ref 'Purpose']]"

pprint(yaml.safe_load(example_yaml))
```

which gives:

```
{'Name': 'EMR {Environment} {Purpose}'}
```

You should not use `load()`, it is documented to be potentially
unsafe, and above all: **it is not necessary here**. Register with the
`SafeLoader` and call `safe_load()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change:

```
def aws_join(loader, node):
    delimiter = loader.construct_scalar(node.value[0])
    value = loader.construct_sequence(node.value[1])
    return delimiter.join(value)
```

Then you will get output:

```
{'Name': 'EMR {Environment} {Purpose}'}
```