# Parsing a YAML with '!' tag via Pyyaml - sequence node parsing

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I am working on parsing a YAML file. I was able to read the data and access them with nested dictionaries. But I tried retrieving the sequence node data, or data with the seq tag and couldn’t parse the same via scan or parse or load.

Example YAML

```
version: !schema 'v1'
version_major: 1
version_minor: 0
version_patch: 0
description:
  more_info: bar
  short_description: foo
depends: !EvaluatableList
- !dependency 'avb@/1.0.0': !And [!Equals [!Ref 'asdf::selected',
      true], !NotEquals [!Ref 'fddg’, wwer]
```

In the above yaml, I couldn’t access the string with ‘!’ exclamation tag.  Those are required to validate the equal or not equal conditions. The output dict also doesn’t read about the ‘!’ tagged information.

On reading the PyYAML documentation, I couldn’t retrieve any information related to the above.

Please let me know if there is any possibility of reading the above.

Comment: this is a similar problem and should help in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883307/parse-nested-custom-yaml-tags

Comment: thanks tinita.. Found the answer from that post along with this https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/11269/yaml.add_constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong documentation, and the wrong library.

If you want to know about `!`, you should consult the [YAML 1.2
 documentation](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html). That character
 indicates a [node tag](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2784064)

PyYAML cannot handle YAML 1.2, it only parses YAML 1.1 (and loads only part of YAML 1.1).

What you want to use is ruamel.yaml (disclaimer: I am the author of
that package). You can install that in your python virtual environment
using: `pip install ruamel.yaml` .

After that you can access the value for the key 'version' as if you loaded dictionary from your YAML
document and other tagged entries appropriately as dictionary or list:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
version: !schema 'v1'
version_major: 1
version_minor: 0
version_patch: 0
description:
  more_info: bar
  short_description: foo
depends: !EvaluatableList
- !dependency 'avb@/1.0.0': !And [!Equals [!Ref 'asdf::selected', 
     true], !NotEquals [!Ref 'fddg', wwer]]
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data['version'])
dep = data['depends'][0]
for k in dep:
    print(k)
    for v in dep[k]:
        print(' ', v[0], v[1])
```

which gives:

```
v1
avb@/1.0.0
  asdf::selected True
  fddg wwer
```

`yaml.load()` can also be given a file handle (opened for
reading) or a `pathlib.Path` (i.e. the instance `Path` instance,
`load` will do the openeing).

Please note that I changed the last line in the YAML file. The
character after `fddg` is not a single quote and another closing
bracket was needed to balance the flow-style sequences in that mapping